# IF cell has value>1 lookup another cells value and place it in a cell.

Tags: excel

I am making an order sheet for our company and if I import the whole sheet into our system it pulls all the items into a sales order even if the value is 0.  I would like to have the sheet place our item number in a separate column if the buyer adds 1 or more to the quantity column.  This way I can map the column with the placed values and it will only import the items with values.

So I have all my part numbers in column E,  and the quantity column is G.  If there is quantity in G, I would like it to reference D in the corresponding row and place that value on a seperate column like N.  This way if there is quantiy it will add the part number then when I import it will only read the ones with quantity.  Any Ideas

IF function
Vlookup?

=IF G1>1 Then = D1     Something like that but work.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column N, you would put something like =IF(G1 > 0, D1,"")

Then when someone enters a value in cell G1, then N1 will copy D1, otherwise it is blank.

You could also use data validation in column G to restrict entries to numbers only.

Comment: Excellent ,  that worked thank you.  It says false though when the quantity is 0.  I will have to see if this causes an error.  Is there a way to make it so the column is blank if there is no quantity?

Comment: @user3330470 are you sure you have entered the formula as written including the "" after the second comma?